# Issues with classes in Python 3: class doesn't recognize variable that was declared within it

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, calculator, self

I am creating a calculator in Python 3 in which you can type a full problem such as:
3 + 2
or
5 * 2
And I want it to be able to calculate just from that info.
Here is the code I already have:

```
# calc.py

import os

class Main:
    def calculate(self):
        # At the moment, \/ this is not in use.
        self.alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
        self.numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        self.operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
        self.prob = input('>>>')
        os.system('cls')
        self.prob.split()
        self.num = 'a'
        for i in range(0, len(self.prob) - 1):
            if self.prob[i] in self.numbers:
                if self.num == 'a':
                    self.a = int(self.prob[i])

                if self.num == 'b':
                    self.b = int(self.prob[i])

            if self.prob[i] in self.operators:
                self.operator = self.prob[i]
                self.num = 'b'

            if self.prob[i] == ' ':
                pass

        if self.operator == '+':
            self.c = self.a + self.b

        elif self.operator == '-':
            self.c = self.a - self.b

        elif self.operator == '*':
            self.c = self.a * self.b

        elif self.operator == '/':
            self.c = self.a / self.b

        print(self.c)
        os.system('pause')
        os.system('cls')        

main = Main()

main.calculate()
```

It's giving me the error below:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\Programs\calc.py", line 48, in <module>
    main.calculate()
  File "C:\Python33\Programs\calc.py", line 31, in calculate
    self.c = self.a + self.b
AttributeError: 'Main' object has no attribute 'a'
```

There is a variable named `self.a` in the Main class, so I'm not sure why it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: You should not even be using a class for this if all you have is one giant function. Just use a function. Also, you're going to have a rough time going about it this way. See [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) for doing this right.

Comment: Hi, the reason I used a class is because I want to be able to easily add on to it later.  For example, I want to add the ability to do basic algebra after I get this part working.

Comment: It's still not a valid class. It defines a "main" object, whatever that is. Try to find good tutorials on class design. You'll thank yourself later.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `self.a` is assigned within a conditional `if` statement, 2 of them in fact. So if both of those conditions aren't met, `self.a` is never assigned, and an error is thrown when you try to use it to calculate `self.c`

Try setting `self.a` and `self.b` to a default value (maybe 0) before the conditional, then if the condition isn't met, it will at least have a default value.

-- EDIT --

actually, for this case you probably don't want to just assign them to 0. But you need to make sure they are defined somehow before you try to use them.